# Get (ONLY) Id of input field using .getAttribute

Tags: jquery, attributes

I have a list of check-boxes which all have unique ID's. When a button is pressed it should pass this list of ID's through to the back-end.
I am able to get the ID's using the .getAttribute method but it includes other information which I don't need. Is there a way to get ONLY the id of that selected check-box?

Here is the basic code that fires when the button is clicked:

```
            $('input[name = "dCodes"]:checked').each(function () {
                selectedCodes.push($(this.getAttribute('id')));
            });
```

Here is what the selectedCodes array contains after the button is clicked:
[image]

Comment: Share an example `html`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you *only* want the `id` string, then don't push a jQuery object in to the array:

```
let selectedCodes = [];
$('input[name="dCodes"]:checked').each(function () {
  selectedCodes.push(this.getAttribute('id'));
});
```

Note that this can be simplified to just retrieve the `id` property directly from the `this` reference without needing `getAttribute()`:

```
let selectedCodes = [];
$('input[name="dCodes"]:checked').each(function () {
  selectedCodes.push(this.id);
});
```

Going a step further still, you can remove the need for the explicit `each()` loop and separate array declaration by using jQuery's `map()` method:

```
let selectedCodes = $('input[name="dCodes"]:checked').map(function () {
  return this.id;
}).get();
```

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly what I needed. I made use of your final solution by making use of ```map()``` method

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `selectedCodes.push($(this).attr('id')));` to get only id value in that array.

Comment: Why create a jQuery object when you can get the `id` from the existing object?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan because the question does not tag `javascript` and OP is more focused on jQuery

Comment: Well jQuery is Javascript, and creating an entire object just to get a single property (which you already have access to) is redundant

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan couldn't this be a snippet of a whole lot of code, you can't judge this way.

Answer (score 0):

`this` should be enclosed.

```
selectedCodes.push($(this).attr('id'));
```

Comment: Why create a jQuery object when you can get the `id` from the existing object?